# Export from Azure Storage Queue to a CSV file

Tags: azure, export, azure-storage, export-to-csv, azure-storage-queues

What is the easiest way to export data from Azure Queue to a *CSV* file without writing codes?

Comment: You would need to use a tool which supports this functionality. If I remember correctly, Storage Explorer (not the Microsoft's one) on CodePlex had this feature (at least downloading the messages from a queue). You may want to check it out. However I am curious why do you want to do it?

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri I found it here https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=azurestorageexplorer .
I was looking for a quick solution to export messages to another system which works with CSV reader.

Comment: You're right, sorry.